# how to re-register zookeeper watches

Tags: java, architecture, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

I want to use zookeeper watches to do some tasks(distributed syncs across multiple nodes) in case of any update on znode. I am aware that zookeeper watchers are one-time triggers and I need to re-register the watchers in order to get future updates. But I am not able to do that in my example.

```
b = zkeeper.getData(path, new Watcher() {
                public void process(WatchedEvent we) {
                    if (we.getState() == Watcher.Event.KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
                        System.out.println("inside get watcher");
                        clear_cache();
                        }
                }
            }, null);
```

This is working for one -time update on znode, but once I update again, zookeeper doesn't trigger anything.

**So, once I receive a trigger, how should I re-register the watcher from triggered event?**

Even if I re-register it inside process function of watcher, it is not working properly.

**Note**: I am using apache-zookeeper java client.

**Use Case**: Need to sync data across multiple node using trigger. For example: if update request reaches one node, it should immediately inform other nodes as well for update.

Comment: You have to register the watch inside your callback again

Comment: use apache curator  https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/persistent-watcher.html

Its hard to get zookeeper recipes right, Apache curator was specially created for that purpose

Comment: See [Persistent, Recursive Watches](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1416)(and [docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_WatchPersistentRecursive)) which implements recursive persistent watchers. If you can upgrade Zookeeper to v3.6, this should help you.

Comment: @codeflush.dev Can you please give a rough code example? Java syntax goes haywire when I try to re-register a watcher inside another. You can't use the same watcher because variable may not have initialized error. If you create another watcher you need yet another watcher inside... it goes on forever

Comment: @uylmz I'm only on my mobile Right now, but I remember that I had a method that essentially registered the watch, which I simply called again when the watch was triggered

Comment: I tried using "this" as the watcher parameter, inside anonymous watcher instance to re register the watcher. It seems to work, although I'm not sure it's the best solution. Never occured to me "this" referred to the anonymous class instance.